# Laravel relationship with multiple table with pivot

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables and pivot (product has options)

```
-products
 -> id
 -> name
 -> price

-options
 -> id
 -> name
 -> option_group_id 

-option_groups
 -> id
 -> name

-option_products
 -> option_id
 -> product_id
```

I get product options with

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Option::class, 'option_products');
}
```

but I want to get the option groups from a product model

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the `option_groups` property from an option. Thus, you don't need another relation. If you want to have all option groups, you can eager load them on the relation using another method on the model. If you only need the option groups, you may then map the resulting collection into a collection of the option groups.

Example:

```php
public function optionsWithGroups()
{
    return $this->options()
        ->with('group')
        ->get();
}

// ...or...

public function optionGroups()
{
    return $this->options()
        ->with('group')
        ->get()
        ->map(fn($option) => $option->group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with "nested eager loading".

```
Products::with('options','options.groups'...)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a [`hasManyThrough` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). Something like:

```php
public function optionGroups()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough(OptionGroup::class, Option::class);
}
```

You may need to explicitly set some of the keys (see [key conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through-key-conventions)).